# gmock - how to mock function with noexcept specifier

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I need to mock the following function:

```
 virtual void fun() noexcept = 0;
```

Is it possible using gmock ?

Gmock has the following macro:`#define GMOCK_METHOD0_(tn, constness, ct, Method, ...)` but there is a comment: `// INTERNAL IMPLEMENTATION - DON'T USE IN USER CODE!!!` Moreover I don't know how to use that macro (what the parameters tn and ct means) ?

**Edit**

The following mock:

```
GMOCK_METHOD0_(, noexcept, ,fun, void());
```

compiles with gmock 1.7.0 but when I compile it using gmock 1.8.1 I get the compilation errors:

```
main.cpp:17: error: expected identifier before ‘noexcept’
 GMOCK_METHOD0_(, noexcept, ,fun, void());
                  ^
gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:153: in definition of macro ‘GMOCK_METHOD0_’
   constness ::testing::internal::Function<__VA_ARGS__>* ) const { \
   ^
main.cpp:17: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘noexcept’
 GMOCK_METHOD0_(, noexcept, ,fun, void());
                  ^
gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:153: in definition of macro ‘GMOCK_METHOD0_’
   constness ::testing::internal::Function<__VA_ARGS__>* ) const { \
   ^
main.cpp:-1: In member function ‘testing::internal::MockSpec<void()> MockX::gmock_fun(const testing::internal::WithoutMatchers&, int) const’:

gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:154: error: ‘AdjustConstness_noexcept’ is not a member of ‘testing::internal’
     return ::testing::internal::AdjustConstness_##constness(this)-> \
            ^
main.cpp:17: in expansion of macro ‘GMOCK_METHOD0_’
 GMOCK_METHOD0_(, noexcept, ,fun, void());
 ^
```

Answer (score 11):

Now this is possible since v1.10.0 with the new syntax.
see [change log](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases) and [new syntax explanation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/72adf7a4155b6642da1e6761678fe546590c0269/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#creating-mock-classes)

The new syntax contains a separate argument specs to pass the qualifiers

```
class MyMock {
   public:
      MOCK_METHOD(ReturnType, MethodName, (Args...), (Specs...));
};
```

Answer (score 7):

On older mock versions one may workaround such a c++-decoration by simple trick:

1. Create mock method without *noexcept*
2. Create proxy method with right signature, which will call mocked method

In your example it would be

```
class Mock : public MyInterface
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(funImpl, void());
  virtual void fun() noexcept
  {
    funImpl();
  }
};
```

Using the same pattern you may mock methods taking non-gmock-friendly arguments like `auto_ptr`. You also create wrapper function and change arguments to gmock-friendly ones inside wrapper (like `shared_ptr`).