# Google Mock and override keyword

Tags: c++, overriding, googlemock

Is there a macro in Google Mock to ensure compile time check of the signature of `f()` by appending the `override` keyword to the macro substitution:

```
struct I
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct MockI
{
    MOCK_METHOD0(f, void()); // this will define another function if f signature changes 
                             // leading to weird runtime test failures
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gmock - how to mock function with noexcept specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047377/gmock-how-to-mock-function-with-noexcept-specifier)

Comment: Actually, I found another question on that topic. It is about `noexcept`, not `override`, but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to upgrade your GoogleMock to 1.10.x version to do that (unless you want to modify the library yourself).

1.10 version has new macro [`MOCK_METHOD`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/v1.10.x/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#writing-the-mock-class) which can use any function specifier (`const`, `noexcept`, `override`, `final`, ...)

`MOCK_METHOD` macro usage:

```
struct MockI: public I
{
    MOCK_METHOD(void, f, (), (override));
};
```

Old macros `MOCK_METHODx` can still be used, but one should prefer to write new mocks using new method when using 1.10.x

Comment: I have 1.8 I guess for now I will continue defining my own macros until our external dependencies will be updated

Answer (score 0):

Simply derive your mock from base pure virtual class.

```
struct MockI : I
{
    MOCK_METHOD0(f, void()); 
};
```

And you will get compile error if signature of `f` is changed in base class only. No upgrade or manual change of gmock is needed.